# Cannot open postgresql pg_hba file

Tags: postgresql

I tried to create a data source in Intellij, but I failed with error `Ident failed for postgres`.

After I switch to user postgres and try to modify pg_hba file, the system tell me to enter password for user postgres, I tried my root password, "admin"and "postgres", but none works.

So I'd like to know whats the default password for user postgres?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no default password for the `postgres` user.  By default, that's a local-only system account that doesn't have a default login.

Further, the `postgres` user doesn't have direct access to edit the `pg_hba` file.  You should be editing that with superuser privileges, not with the `postgres` user.

Edit the file with superuser - pure `sudo` and a command line to access it.  DO NOT try and edit `pg_hba.conf` with just the postgres user, use `root` who actually owns the files.

Comment: I tried using root to edit it, but it shows cannot connect error.

Comment: @BroLegend I'm confused, can you include the full error message as well as what you're trying to run to edit the file?  Something sounds amiss on your system.

Comment: No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:2463): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0

Comment: Why are you using `gedit`?  Use the command line and a command line text editor.

Comment: After I deleted data folder and re-init db, DB works fine now.